# Method Pro(k) C#

Tags: c#, methods

I  have to do this example for my course work and I'm unsure what should I have to do with last case.

> Create a method Pro(k) that generates k number of random integers and returns the sum of those in the interval [-10, 10]. In the main method, enter 3 positive integers a, b and c. To find and print: Pro( |c-b| ) * Pro(a).

This is my code for now:

In Main()

```
        Console.Write("Enter k: ");
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Pro(k);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter а = ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter b = ");
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter c = ");
        int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(Pro(c-b) * Pro(a));

    //method Pro(k) is out of Main()
    public static int Pro(int k)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (num <= 10 && num >= -10)
            {
                sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + sum);
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: To find and print: Pro( |c-b| ) * Pro(a) , this part is missing in program. Kindly do not expect someone to write code for you.

Comment: I just dont understad the logic of this formule Pro(|c-b|) * Pro(a).....I should use Pro(k) for solving it or I should make another method Pro

Comment: @FatmaSahatchieva you think it in the proper way, the only thing to improve was the console writeline and the random that generates values! keep learning and keep growing! have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct answer |c-b| = Math.Abs(c-b) and it said Generates, not insert inside pro function so you should use random with interval (-10,10) te get those numbers. Anyway you advance a lot! please a console.writeline inside a method that return a value, also is a bad practice, you should return it first and then print it! hope it helps you!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter k: ");
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + Pro(k));
        

        Console.WriteLine("Enter а = ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter b = ");
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter c = ");
        int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(Pro(Math.Abs(c - b))* Pro(a));
    }
    public static int Pro(int k)
    {
        int sum = 0; 
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            int rand_num = rd.Next(-10,10);
            sum = sum + rand_num;   
        }
        return sum;
    }
```